# Unit Testing Flink Streams with Multiple Event Streams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 2 `DataStream`s that I connect and feed into a `CoFlatMap` function. I need to be able to test generating messages on two different `DataStream`s, but coordinating when the messages arrive. How does one go about doing that in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with: https://github.com/ottogroup/flink-spector/

The documentation could use a little updating, but overall it works really well. Here's the `pom.xml` entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.flinkspector</groupId>
        <artifactId>flinkspector-datastream_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the official [unit testing guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/testing.html). Check especially last paragraphs regarding using TestHarness. In your case it seems like you should use [TwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/util/TwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness.java). You can find example how to use it in [CoProcessOperatorTest](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/co/CoProcessOperatorTest.java)